# Yii2 - Working With Multiple backend- session and cookies

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Let me tell you the case.
Basically I have separate backend in yii2 advanced template.
Why ? This is the reason

My office have a lot of branch office in a country with a lot of departements of each branch.

This departements, I have interpretation of them as modules.
The departement name is same but sometime, they have a lot of different 
behaviours.

As example admin in headquarters can erase employee name in branch 
office, but admin branch office , they can not.

So, I choose to separate them into backend folder each like this :

```
backend  (which is portal branch and also super-admin backend)
  -modules
    -human_resource

backend-jkt (which is Jakarta Indonesia backend)
  -modules
    -human_resource
```

[image]

My question is :

When user successfully login to backend, then i created a link to backend-jkt, it's automatically login also.

As vice versa,

When people directly to backend-jkt but not logged in to backend,  it's automatically redirect to backend's login,

*Now my situation is: when user logged in to backend, then click link "Jakarta" as above in image, user have to sign in again.*

**This is my config in backend**

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-backend',
    'name' => 'Backend System',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [
        'mimin' => [
            'class' => '\hscstudio\mimin\Module',
        ],
        'SuperAdmin' => [
            'class' => 'backend\modules\super_admin\SuperAdmin',
        ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_identity-backend',
                'httpOnly' => true
            ],
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the backend
            'name' => 'advanced-backend',
            'savePath' => sys_get_temp_dir(),
        ],
        'request' => [
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'IkR77lm93Rcb9TCoYTAZ',
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
        ],

        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'dmstr\web\AdminLteAsset' => [

                ],
            ],
        ],

        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'suffix' => '.html',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],

        'urlManagerBackendJkt' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
            'baseUrl' => '/backend-jkt/web/',

            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'http://jkt.tresnamuda.local/' => '@app/index',
            ],
        ],
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager', // only support DbManager
        ],

    ],
    'as access' => [
        'class' => '\hscstudio\mimin\components\AccessControl',
        'allowActions' => [
            // add wildcard allowed action here!
            'site/*',
            'debug/*',
            // 'mimin/*', // only in dev mode
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

**And this is the backend-jkt**

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../backend/config/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../backend/config/params-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-backend_jkt',
    'name' => 'Jkt Backend System',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'backend_jkt\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'modules' => [
        'mimin' => [
            'class' => '\hscstudio\mimin\Module',
        ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_identity-backend',
                'httpOnly' => true
            ],
        ],
        'session' => [
            // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the backend
            'name' => 'advanced-backend',
            'savePath' => sys_get_temp_dir(),
        ],
        'request' => [
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'IkR77lm93Rcb9TCoYTAZ',
            'csrfParam' => '_csrf-backend',
        ],

        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'dmstr\web\AdminLteAsset' => [

                ],
            ],
        ],

        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'suffix' => '.html',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],

        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager', // only support DbManager
        ],

    ],
    'as access' => [
        'class' => '\hscstudio\mimin\components\AccessControl',
        'allowActions' => [
            // add wildcard allowed action here!
            'site/*',
            'debug/*',
            // 'mimin/*', // only in dev mode
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

your question about cookies that place in user's browsers seprate by domain and Path  , so you have to store it for next domain Path , I recommend  to you after  clicking Jakarta send user-id and private-key to Jakarta and there force login that user-id by simple command :

```
if(private-key is Okey and you get $user-id by POST ) {

$user = User::findOne($user-id);
Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user);

}
```

private-key is simple or advance why that you can increase your security , you may leave it and just check have user-id or not !